# Not all martingales $Y$ can be represented $Y = H\bullet X$ for a given $X$

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

This is given as a counterexample that not all martingales $Y$ with $Y_0 = 0$ can be represented as $H\bullet X$ (= "discrete stochastic integral" ... wherever this term comes from??) for a given martingale $X$ with $X_0 = 0$:

[image]

Why does the author write "there is no number"? Shouldn't it be "there is no random variable, such ..." or "there are no number**s**, such ..."?

Answer (score 1):

The random variable $H_1$ has to be time $0$ measureable which makes it a constant.

Comment: Why? It could be that $\mathcal{F}_0 = \{A, A^c, \emptyset, \Omega\}$ with $\mathbf{P}[A] = \frac{1}{3}$, that's not incompatible with the definition of $X_0, X_1$.

Comment: He says $\sigma(X)$ martingale, this suggests we are talking about the filtration generated by $X.$